# How to check github commit history from all branches of a repository?

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-status

We had a repository in GitHub with nearly 10-15 branches, developers are committed nearly 3-4 branches on a typical day. *I need to check who is committed and who is not from all those branches.* please guide me, how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

May be would be helpful for you to use TortoiseGit

Comment: I Need to automate this from Linux Server, using Tortoise Git won't be possible i hope.

Comment: you want to install tool on server and have access through http?

Comment: It can't be installed on remote machines. No particular use of Tortoise Git. Why, because even if we clone the data it will give you master branch data or updates only not all the branches.

Comment: I am not sure that it's suitable for you, personally I am using for development intellij idea 14, and this one has very nice version control log graph, and you able to see history of all branches or for particular branch